# CSS3 KeyFrame Translate Animation - Severe Frame Skipping in Android

Tags: android, html, css, jquery-mobile, css-animations

Its very surprising that a simple translate animation ( on a small rectangle ) is skipping frames on a Android 2.2 browser. Its not even 10 frames per second. The handset is Samsung Galaxy Ace ( S5830 ). There are no other animation on the image. Attached below is the code. Am I doing something wrong because I never expected such a simple translate animation to be so bad. Please suggest any workarounds for some acceptable smoothness

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">

    #di1, #ci1 {position: absolute;left:0px;top:0px;-webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;}

.anim1{
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-name: animation1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:1 ;

}

@-webkit-keyframes animation1
{
    0%{ -webkit-transform: translate(25px, 25px) }
    50%{ -webkit-transform: translate(200px, 00px) }
    100%{ -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 200px) }
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

    window.addEventListener("load",win_load,false);

    function win_load()        
    {
        var c=document.getElementById("ci1");var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.fillStyle="#ff0000";
        ctx.fillRect(25,25,30,30);

    }

</script>
```

Comment: But animation in only one direction i.e translate in only x direction or y direction is of acceptable quality. The moment there is a slope all hell break lose and the animation is pathetic

Comment: At what version of Android things get better and acceptable

Answer (score -1):

This is hacky workaround.

In the transform rule add

```
rotateZ(0deg);
```

so that it becomes

```
-webkit-transform:rotateZ(0deg) translate(30,40);
```

this forces webkit to use hardware acceleration if available and improvises performance by bits.

Though there is no garuntee for this to work.

And the animations get sleek after android 3.x , try them out.

Comment: This trick does not work because hardware acceleration does not work in Samsung Galaxy Ace ( S5830 ) having Android 2.2

Comment: yes I did try, though useful information that the trickit works on Galaxy Y. another information is that the moment I remove the 50% keyframe there's no problem.

Comment: why dont u do this with css-transition and JavaScript then ? you can make it translate in frames then apply other frame , yeah this sounds epicly stupid but might work as it wont have to calculate the whole animation just 1 transition ( or 1 method of transition )

Comment: because what I posted is a mere sample. I have far more complicated animations with 100s of keyframes and breaking that into transitions which gets applied via javascript will make the animation slow

Comment: Hmm. 100s of keyframes will ofcourse slow ur animation down , consider the device specs!